# Angular directive inside Play Framework application

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm adding some angularJs functions inside an existing Play Framework 2.0 application.

The angularjs files are served inside the `public/` folder. Everything works fine until I'm trying to use a directive with a separated template:

The directive js `multi-charts.js` and the directive template `multi-charts.html` are all placed in the same directory `components/directives`.
So the full path for the files would be:

- `public/components/directives/multi-charts.js`
- `public/components/directives/multi-charts.html`

The problem is that I cant' reach the template file inside the directive using `templateUrl`.

The directive:

```
app.directive('multiCharts', ['chartService', function(chartService){
    return {
        restrict: 'EACM',
        templateUrl: 'components/directives/multi-charts.html',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        }
    }}]);
```

Running the application the template is not achievable:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/company/components/directives/multi-chart.html 404 (Not Found)
```

Changing the paths inside `templateUrl` doesn't change the error.

I'm missing something, is there a way to refer to a `html` template in a directive served by the internal Play Framework web server?

Comment: multi-charts.html != multi-chart.html your missing the s or was that just a typo in the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.
Adding a new route to the play framework `routes` file:

```
# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file                               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

I'm able to reach the template at:

```
templateUrl: '../assets/js/angular/directives/multi-charts.html'
```